# How Do You Make a 'Rules Link' Work in a Custom Content Pane?

Tags: rules

I'm struggling to get a Rules Link set in a Custom Content Pane to trigger a Rules Link and work. I've done many tests and using the URL path provided by the Rules Link Edit page, (ie domain/content/post-new-content) all I get is a 404 despite my many trials and viewing/reading of info docs online.

Put simply, I want a link set on a Custom Content Pane to show a link which the user clicks, this will then trigger a Rules set to check: a) the user has valid auth/role; B) and then redirect to a Post page; if not authorised then redirect to a 'Subscription' page. Through my testing, a 'standard' link to an Add Content page works fine, so I presume it is something within the Rules/Rules Link  framework I working within the D7.2x

Can someone please provide some generalism how this (assumed simple flow) should work. HELP!

Comment: Whilst the Rules Documentation says you can only add a Rules Link via a View, my above question ponders the whether a link URL can be triggered as a simple link ie  "post-new-content" in a Custom Content pane. Todate I cannot get the trigger to work as it results in only a 404-error yet if I create the same in a View, it works, at least to the re-directed page I require; next I require the Rule to first check that the user has a 'Paid' role in order to have the set permission to post. Has anyone successfully managed to post A Rules Link in a Custom Content pane and what did you do exactly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a Rules link programmatically use the following:

```
<?php
    print render(rules_link_render('RULES_LINK_NAME', $node->nid));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TheMGamer. Just the answer a learning novice need today (-: This answer now give me so many more options with Rules Link as a PHP embed.

Comment: @PaulB up vote my answer and accept my answer as the best if it is easy for you! Thank you